# Create a new row with IF - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to 'split/copy' a row if an IF-Condition (e.g. a cell contains a value) is true...

For example I've got this table:

```
d = {'Invited_guest': ["Max", "Luca", "John", "Biran", "Ian"], 'Age': [19, 21, 32, 45, 34], 'Origin' : ['US', 'UK', 'GER', 'ITA', 'FRA'],'FamilyMember_1': ["Paul", "Anna", "Peter", "Lewis", "Jeremy"], 'FamilyMember_2': ['Rene', 'Ruben', 'Calvin', 'George', 'Silke'], 'FamilyMember_3': ['', 'Olivia', '', '', 'Selina']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

| Index | Invited_guest | Age | Origin | FamilyMember_1 | FamilyMember_2 | FamilyMember_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Max | 19 | US | Paul | Rene |  |
| 1 | Luca | 21 | UK | Anna | Ruben | Olivia |
| 2 | John | 32 | GER | Peter | Calvin |  |
| 3 | Brian | 45 | ITA | Lewis | George |  |
| 4 | Ian | 34 | FRA | Jeremy | Silke | Selina |

So what I want to do is if there is more than one familymember the row gets splited and copied with just one familymember....Like this:

| Index | Invited_guest | Age | Origin | FamilyMember |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Max | 19 | US | Paul |
| 1 | Max | 19 | US | Rene |
| 2 | Luca | 21 | UK | Anna |
| 3 | Luca | 21 | UK | Ruben |
| 4 | Luca | 21 | UK | Anna |
| 5 | Luca | 21 | UK | Olivia |
| 6 | John | 32 | GER | Peter |
| 7 | John | 32 | GER | Calvin |
| 8 | Brian | 45 | ITA | Lewis |
| 9 | Brian | 45 | ITA | George |
| 10 | Ian | 34 | FRA | Jeremy |
| 11 | Ian | 34 | FRA | Silke |
| 12 | Ian | 34 | FRA | Selina |

I hope my question is understandable...

Maybe I should say that I'm quite new to pandas and python and I'm very thankful for any idea, tip and remark :D it's just a practise for myselfe, don't know if this is a 'real world problem' :DD

Comment: You can use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to av

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and [`agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) to convert each row of `FamilyMember` names to a list (and use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to remove empty ones), then [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the result back to the dataframe, and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) that column:

```
exploded = df.assign(names=df.filter(like='FamilyMember_').T.melt().pipe(lambda x: x[x['value'] != '']).groupby('variable')['value'].agg(list)).explode('names').drop(df.filter(like='FamilyMember_'), axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> exploded
   Invited_guest  Age Origin   names
0            Max   19     US    Paul
1            Max   19     US    Rene
2           Luca   21     UK    Anna
3           Luca   21     UK   Ruben
4           Luca   21     UK  Olivia
5           John   32    GER   Peter
6           John   32    GER  Calvin
7          Brian   45    ITA   Lewis
8          Brian   45    ITA  George
9            Ian   34    FRA  Jeremy
10           Ian   34    FRA   Silke
11           Ian   34    FRA  Selina
```

#### Explanation

First, we select the columns that start with `FamilyMember_`:

```
>>> family_members = df.filter(like='FamilyMember_')
>>> family_members
  FamilyMember_1 FamilyMember_2 FamilyMember_3
0           Paul           Rene               
1           Anna          Ruben         Olivia
2          Peter         Calvin               
3          Lewis         George               
4         Jeremy          Silke         Selina
```

Next, we rotate that 90 degrees (also known as *transposing*) for later use with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
>>> family_members.T
                   0       1       2       3       4
FamilyMember_1  Paul    Anna   Peter   Lewis  Jeremy
FamilyMember_2  Rene   Ruben  Calvin  George   Silke
FamilyMember_3        Olivia                  Selina
```

Then, we'll `melt` it:

```
>>> family_members.T.melt()
    variable   value
0          0    Paul
1          0    Rene
2          0        
3          1    Anna
4          1   Ruben
5          1  Olivia
6          2   Peter
7          2  Calvin
8          2        
9          3   Lewis
10         3  George
11         3        
12         4  Jeremy
13         4   Silke
14         4  Selina
```

Now we need to remove the empty items. We could do that like this:

```
x = family_members.T.melt()
x = x[x['values'] != '']
```

...but that's multiple lines, which won't do in a one-liner. So we can use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) with a lambda function to achieve exactly this in a one-liner fashion:

```
>>> family_members.T.melt().pipe(lambda x: x[x['value'] != ''])
    variable   value
0          0    Paul
1          0    Rene
3          1    Anna
4          1   Ruben
5          1  Olivia
6          2   Peter
7          2  Calvin
9          3   Lewis
10         3  George
12         4  Jeremy
13         4   Silke
14         4  Selina
```

Then we can group by the `variable` column as it groups together perfectly those names that need to go together:

```
>>> g = family_members.T.melt().pipe(lambda x: x[x['value'] != '']).groupby('variable')
>>> g
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x12b131e50>

# That's not very useful, so we can convert it to a list to have a peek at what's inside:
>>> list(g)
[(0,
     variable value
  0         0  Paul
  1         0  Rene),
 (1,
     variable   value
  3         1    Anna
  4         1   Ruben
  5         1  Olivia),
 (2,
     variable   value
  6         2   Peter
  7         2  Calvin),
 (3,
      variable   value
  9          3   Lewis
  10         3  George),
 (4,
      variable   value
  12         4  Jeremy
  13         4   Silke
  14         4  Selina)]
```

We need to convert each of those groups to a list of the names contained inside them. That's where [`agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) comes in:

```
>>> g['value'].agg(list)
variable
0               [Paul, Rene]
1      [Anna, Ruben, Olivia]
2            [Peter, Calvin]
3            [Lewis, George]
4    [Jeremy, Silke, Selina]
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Perfect. Now we need to put that column back on the dataframe. We could just assign it like normal:

```
g['names'] = g['value'].agg(list)
```

...but again, that would make a one-liner impossible. Fortunately, there's the [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) function, which is built for this use-case:

```
>>> df.assign(names=g['value'].agg(list))
  Invited_guest  Age Origin FamilyMember_1 FamilyMember_2 FamilyMember_3                    names
0           Max   19     US           Paul           Rene                            [Paul, Rene]
1          Luca   21     UK           Anna          Ruben         Olivia    [Anna, Ruben, Olivia]
2          John   32    GER          Peter         Calvin                         [Peter, Calvin]
3         Biran   45    ITA          Lewis         George                         [Lewis, George]
4           Ian   34    FRA         Jeremy          Silke         Selina  [Jeremy, Silke, Selina]
```

(Note that `assign` is NOT in-place. It modifies a new copy of the dataframe, not the original).

Finally, we use the magic [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) (only available in pandas 0.25 and newer):

```
>>> df.assign(names=g['value'].agg(list)).explode('names')
  Invited_guest  Age Origin FamilyMember_1 FamilyMember_2 FamilyMember_3   names
0           Max   19     US           Paul           Rene                   Paul
0           Max   19     US           Paul           Rene                   Rene
1          Luca   21     UK           Anna          Ruben         Olivia    Anna
1          Luca   21     UK           Anna          Ruben         Olivia   Ruben
1          Luca   21     UK           Anna          Ruben         Olivia  Olivia
2          John   32    GER          Peter         Calvin                  Peter
2          John   32    GER          Peter         Calvin                 Calvin
3         Biran   45    ITA          Lewis         George                  Lewis
3         Biran   45    ITA          Lewis         George                 George
4           Ian   34    FRA         Jeremy          Silke         Selina  Jeremy
4           Ian   34    FRA         Jeremy          Silke         Selina   Silke
4           Ian   34    FRA         Jeremy          Silke         Selina  Selina
```

And of course, remove the only `FamilyMember_*` columns:

```
>>> family_member_columns = df.filter(like='FamilyMember_').columns
>>> family_member_columns
Index(['FamilyMember_1', 'FamilyMember_2', 'FamilyMember_3'], dtype='object')

>>> df.assign(names=g['value'].agg(list)).explode('names').drop(family_member_columns, axis=1)
```

Comment: I love the way you did it in a one liner ! +1

Comment: Haha, yeah, but yours is much simpler. I'm not great with `melt` :|

Comment: Hey thanks for your idea / solution :D

Comment: I'll provide an explanation :)

Comment: @Quax97 check my answer now for a (hopefully!) in-depth explanation :)

Comment: Haha thanks a lot @richardec and tlentali for your support :D.... That's way more help than I expected :D

Answer (score 1):

First, we get all the columns starting by `FamilyMember_`.
Then, we can use [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to get the expected result.
To get a clean output, we can drop the `melt` created output `variable`, then we drop the `NaN` values as some `Invited_guest` don't have a `FamilyMember_3`, we sort the values by `Invited_guest` and reset the index to get a clean ordered final `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> keys = [c for c in df if c.startswith('FamilyMember_')]
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Invited_guest', 'Age', 'Origin'], value_vars=keys, value_name='key').drop('variable', axis=1).dropna().sort_values('Invited_guest').reset_index(drop=True)
    Invited_guest   Age     Origin  key
0   Brian           45      ITA     Lewis
1   Brian           45      ITA     George
2   Ian             34      FRA     Jeremy
3   Ian             34      FRA     Silke
4   Ian             34      FRA     Selina
5   John            32      GER     Peter
6   John            32      GER     Calvin
7   Luca            21      UK      Anna
8   Luca            21      UK      Ruben
9   Luca            21      UK      Olivia
10  Max             19      US      Paul
11  Max             19      US      Rene
```

Comment: Instead of `keys = [c for c in df if c.startswith('FamilyMember_')]`, you could also use `keys = df.filter(like='FamilyMember_').columns` - if you want. Not necessary, just a different option :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, it does what it should do :D now i trying to understand your ideas :D the one by @richardec is quite difficult due to the lambda function :)